# How to get HTML response body in RobotFramework

Tags: python, automated-tests, robotframework

I'm failing to get a response body from a Get request.
This is what I get when I run it on Postman:

[image: Postman response body as HTML]

But when I go to Robotframework and send the `Get On Session` request I can not get such info. This is what I get from the `response` object:

This the requests call code:

```
${response}         GET On Session    API_${SUITE_NAME}   myURL     json=${PARAMS}   headers=${HEADERS}      expected_status=${desired_status_code}
```

And the returns:

```
${response.status_code} = 200
${response.headers} = {'Date': 'Thu, 02 Feb 2023 19:14:02 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Content-Length': '0', 'Connection': 'close', 'access-control-allow-origin': '*', 'vary': 'Origin'}
content: ""
cookies: <RequestsCookieJar[]>
text: ""
OK: true
history: []
url: The URL I used on this cal: Create Session    API_${SUITE_NAME}    ${URL_API}   verify=true
```

And this is for the response.json()

```
${response.json()} = [FAIL (+0.01s)] Resolving variable '${response.json()}' failed: JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Can you tell me how to get this HTML so I can interact with it?

Answer (score 1):

This is my code:

```
${response.text}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to use the `Get` instead of `Get on Session`

So my request would be like this:

```
${response}     Get     url=theURL    params=theParams
```